# Handling grapheme clusters in Dart

Tags: unicode, dart, flutter, icu, grapheme-cluster

From what I can tell Dart does not have support for grapheme clusters, though there is talk of supporting it:

- [Dart Strings should support Unicode grapheme cluster operations #34](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/34)
- [Minimal Unicode grapheme cluster support #49](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/49)

Until it is implemented, what are my options for iterating through grapheme clusters? For example, if I have a string like this:

```
String family = '\u{1F468}\u{200D}\u{1F469}\u{200D}\u{1F467}'; // ‍‍
String myString = 'Let me introduce my $family to you.';
```

and there is a cursor after the five-codepoint family emoji:

[image]

How would I move the cursor one user-perceived character to the left?

(In this particular case I know the size of the grapheme cluster so I could do it, but what I am really asking about is finding the length of an arbitrarily long grapheme cluster.)

**Update**

I see from [this article](https://oleb.net/blog/2017/11/swift-4-strings/) that Swift uses the system's [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) library. Something similar may be possible in Flutter.

### Supplemental code

For those who want to play around with my example above, here is a demo project. The buttons move the cursor to the right or left. It currently takes 8 button presses to move the cursor past the family emoji.

[image]

*main.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Grapheme cluster testing')),
        body: BodyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyWidgetState createState() => _BodyWidgetState();
}

class _BodyWidgetState extends State<BodyWidget> {

  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(
      text: 'Let me introduce my \u{1F468}\u{200D}\u{1F469}\u{200D}\u{1F467} to you.'
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          controller: controller,
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('<<'),
                onPressed: () {
                  _moveCursorLeft();
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('>>'),
                onPressed: () {
                  _moveCursorRight();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void _moveCursorLeft() {
    int currentCursorPosition = controller.selection.start;
    if (currentCursorPosition == 0)
      return;
    int newPosition = currentCursorPosition - 1;
    controller.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: newPosition, extentOffset: newPosition);
  }

  void _moveCursorRight() {
    int currentCursorPosition = controller.selection.end;
    if (currentCursorPosition == controller.text.length)
      return;
    int newPosition = currentCursorPosition + 1;
    controller.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: newPosition, extentOffset: newPosition);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give some code example of moving the cursor? Is it something like `moveCursorTo(Int index)`?

Comment: @TruongSinh, You can move the cursor by setting int offsets in the `TextSelection`. I added a demo project to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/icu

Sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


import 'dart:async';
import 'package:icu/icu.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Grapheme cluster testing')),
        body: BodyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyWidgetState createState() => _BodyWidgetState();
}

class _BodyWidgetState extends State<BodyWidget> {
  final ICUString icuText = ICUString('Let me introduce my \u{1F468}\u{200D}\u{1F469}\u{200D}\u{1F467} to you.\u{1F468}\u{200D}\u{1F469}\u{200D}\u{1F467}');
  TextEditingController controller;
  _BodyWidgetState() {
    controller = TextEditingController(
      text: icuText.toString()
  );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          controller: controller,
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('<<'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await _moveCursorLeft();
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('>>'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await _moveCursorRight();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void _moveCursorLeft() async {
    int currentCursorPosition = controller.selection.start;
    if (currentCursorPosition == 0)
      return;
    int newPosition = await icuText.previousGraphemePosition(currentCursorPosition);
    controller.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: newPosition, extentOffset: newPosition);
  }

  void _moveCursorRight() async {
    int currentCursorPosition = controller.selection.end;
    if (currentCursorPosition == controller.text.length)
      return;
    int newPosition = await icuText.nextGraphemePosition(currentCursorPosition);
    controller.selection = TextSelection(baseOffset: newPosition, extentOffset: newPosition);
  }
}
```

---

Original answer:

Until Dart/Flutter fully implements ICU, I think your best bet is to use [PlatformChannel](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to pass the Unicode string native (iOS Swift4+ or Android Java/Kotlin) to iterate/manupuliate there, and send back the result.

- For Swift4+, it's out-of-the-box as the article you mention (not Swift3-, not ObjC)
- For Java/Kotlin, replace Oracle's `BreakIterator` with [ICU library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j)'s, which works much better. No changes aside from import statements.

The reason I suggest to use native manipulation (instead of doing it on Dart) is because Unicode has too many things to handle, such as normalization, canonical equivalence, ZWNJ, ZWJ, ZWSP, etc.

Comment down if you need some sample code.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a native Dart answer, but you are probably right. If you have sample code, that would be great, but your answer is fine as it is too.

Comment: Actually let me see if I can wrap it in a plugin, so code authors don't have to interact with native Swift/Java so much

Comment: Great! That is a big help!

Comment: @TruongSinh Do you have any plans on migrating your plugin to AndroidX? I also suggest you linking your Github repository in Flutter Packages.

Comment: how to import ICU library in kotlin? is it simply add a statement import icu?

Answer (score 6):

## 2020 update

Use the [characters](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) package by the Dart team. It's now the official way to handle grapheme clusters.

Use `text.characters` to get the grapheme clusters. User `text.characters.iterator` to move over them. I'm still working out how to convert `CharacterRange` to `TextSelection`. I'll update this answer later when I have more details.

***Note**: This is a complete rewrite of my old answer. See the edit history for details.*