# How to convert String index to character index in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, unicode, grapheme-cluster

If I have an arbitrary String like this:

```dart
final family = '\u{1F468}\u{200D}\u{1F469}\u{200D}\u{1F467}'; // ‍‍
final myString = 'Let me introduce my $family to you.';
```

And I know the String index of the character after the family emoji (the space) is `28`, how do I find the String index of the first code unit of the family emoji? In other words, how to I find the length in UTF-16 code units of the family emoji?

[image]

I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54483177/handling-grapheme-clusters-in-dart) before, but that was before the [characters](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) package came out. Is there anything I can do to map the grapheme cluster index to the String index?

The reason I'm asking is that I want to programmatically backspace by grapheme cluster inside a Flutter TextField.

Comment: Isn't `family.length` is the length of `family` in UTF-16 code units?

Comment: @jamesdlin, Yes, I wrote it like that to make the string more readable, but I guess that was misleading. What I'd like know is how to find the length for some arbitrary unknown grapheme cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that String.characters gives you a list of one grapheme cluster per element.  Just remove the stuff a character at a time using a range as described in the docs (https://pub.dev/documentation/characters/latest/characters/CharacterRange-class.html).

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding how `CharacterRange` works.